# Use Rouche`s theorem to prove # of zeros

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

For a fixed $\lambda$ satisfying $\vert\lambda\vert$ < 1, show that $(z - 1)^n e^z + \lambda (z + 1)^n$ has
n zeros in the right half-plane, which are all simple if $\lambda \not=$ 0.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Use $f(z) = (z-1)^ne^z$ and $g(z) = \lambda (z+1)^n$. Obviously, $f$ has $n$ zeros in the right half plane...

Comment: but how can I prove the inequality on the boundary when $\vert z\vert=R$ ? what we have here is $e^z$ so the inequality is not correct?

Comment: Why $|z| = R$??? What is the boundary here?

Comment: I took a semicircle in the right half plane since Rouche`s theorem should be applied to a bounded domain and I want to prove the inequality on this half semicircle and then let R goes to infinity.

Comment: It might be easier with a rectangular domain. On the imaginary axis the inequality is fulfilled. I just checked that when $z = t - iR$ for $R$ large enough (e.g., $R^4/(1+R^2) > 4n$) the inequality is also satisfied. It remains to check for $z = t + iR$ (which should be similar) and $z = r + is$, $s\in [-R,R]$ and $r > 1$ (can be chosen arbitrarily).

Comment: Just checked $z = r+is$. Works! You just have to choose $r$ large enough.

Comment: thanks, I`ll try to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took a semicircle in the right half plane. Good idea!
$$
(z - 1)^n e^z + \lambda (z + 1)^n=0\iff \left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^n+\lambda e^{-z}=0,$$
since $z+1\ne 0$ for $z$ with $\operatorname{Re}z>0.$

Let $f(z)=\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^n,$ $g(z)=\lambda e^{-z}.$ 
Take a semicircle in the right half plane with radius $R$ sufficiently large such that $\left(\frac{R-1}{R+1}\right)^n>\lambda$, then
$$
|f(z)|\ge \left(\frac{|z|-1}{|z|+1}\right)^n=\left(\frac{R-1}{R+1}\right)^n>\lambda \quad \text{for } z\,(|z|=R)
$$
and $$
|f(z)|=1\quad \text{for } z=it, t\in \mathbb{R}.$$
So $|f(z)|> \lambda$ on the boundary of the semicircle.
On the contrary 
$$
|\lambda e^{-z}|=\lambda e^{-\operatorname{Re}z}\le \lambda,$$
since $\operatorname{Re}z\ge 0.$